# MATLAB 3d plotting data coordinates

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, 3d

Ok so I have a set of data. First is the distance, Second is an orientation. I have both in degrees and o'clock formats ( its a circular data)
data will look like this.

Miles___    o'clock  ___     Degrees

.01  _____      0:00 _____        0

.02 _____       1:00 _____       20

.03 _____       2:00  _____       40

.04 _____       1:00 _____        20

etc

I want to plot a 3d graph using this data I have in an excel spreadsheet. the finished result will somewhat like a spring or coil like image.
The problem i'm running into is how to convert the x and y data I have to x,y,z data. Any recommendations on what would be the best approach to convert the oclock or degrees into the y and z data I need to plot? Thanks.

Comment: Your data consists of points on a plane, so it's not clear where the values of z coordinate should come from. Since you want 3D, the points should be at some "height" above/below the xy plane, but what should the height be?

Comment: that can be arbitrary, this is mostly for visual demonstration purposes to show a tools rotation throughout the distance. I want to be able to translate the degrees or oclock into a 3 dimensional graph somehow

Comment: Distance and angle can be converted into x and y: see [polar coordinate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates). They are not related to z. You'll have to make z coordinate yourself, for example `z=linspace(a,b,n)` to make the points uniformly spaced between z=a and z=b.